# Is there any way to use Viber on a tablet without a gsm module?

Tags: tablet, viber-messenger

The tablet has a wifi, a microphone and a speaker. It would be ideal to make calls with, but Viber states it is incompatible. Is there any way around this?

Comment: Does the playstore state this -- or the app when/after being installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It just can't be done. Similarly WhatsApp too doesn't work on non GSM devices.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Install [Viber](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.viber.voip&hl=en) on tablet.
Once it asks for phone number give any cell phone number where you can receive the confirmation code from Viber service.
Try to activate the account.
Once you receive the activation code on the cell.. put the same activation code on the tablet and you are good to receive calls on the same device. Make sure you don't activate this Viber cellphone number on any other device.

Comment: I tried that, but google play said it was incompatible